# In unity, how to make default cylinder top or bottom face forward specific target position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

here is my code:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class TestCylinderLookAt : MonoBehaviourExt
{
    private GameObject target;

    void Start()
    {
        target = GameObject.Find("TargetSphere");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        transform.LookAt(target.transform.position);
    }
}
#endif
```

and here is my try:

[image]

I don't expect cylinder side to forward target, I expect cylinder top or bottom face forward target, how should i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could apply a **local-space rotation** of 90 degrees in your cylinder after you perform the LookAt() operation, as the following:

```
void Update()
{
    transform.LookAt(target.transform.position);
    transform.Rotate(90, 0, 0, Space.Self);
}
```

Comment: The rotation should be done in the Start function. Doing it in the Update function will make it rotate every frame. I am sure you want the rotation to happen just once

Comment: By looking at OP's gif, I understand OP needs the cylinder to be constantly pointing to the sphere, as it moves. Applying the rotation in Start() method would make to the call to LookAt() ovewrite that rotation during Update(), and lead to the same result OP is currently having (a "misaligned" cylinder).

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I missed the LookAt part.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

## Option 1: Make your own cylinder

If you model your own cylinder, you can have the Z axis oriented any way you like.

## Option 2: Reparenting

Create an empty game object as a child of the cylinder, set its position to `(0,0,0)`, then reorder the hierarchy so that the empty object is now the parent of the cylinder. Rotate the cylinder so that its top faces its parent's Z axis.

Remember to adjust any scripts and references such that they target the parent object instead of the model.

Comment: as always @Draco18s is on it. this is correct. also this question is likely a duplicate

Comment: @asullaherc if you dont have modeling software option two is sufficient, its important to remembmer that an objects forward facing direction is the one with the blue arrow denoting the z axis

Comment: @Vanethrane There's probably a dupe around somewhere, but I can't think of a good search term to go looking for it, as they tend to be worded in a way that is project specific.

Comment: thats why i didn't tag it. i have only been here a month. i know you can go back and edit posts, is there a way to go back and edit question titles retro actively? to broaden some of them out? im just curious